# .NET Core: How to send to /Account/Login instead of /Identity/Account/Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Project is in .NET Core 2.2 and uses Identity.
When a user logs in and the session times out he is redirected to the login page by the attribute `[Authorize]` in the controller. Unfortunately the user is redirected to /Identity/Account/Login instead of /Account/Login and the design is different. I would need the redirect to be to /Account/Login. What am I missing?

I have the following in ConfigureServices:

```
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 4;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);      // 20 minutes logged in session timeout
    });
```

I thought options.LoginPath was the way to go...

Comment: Are you calling `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cookie-settings)

Comment: Calling `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after calling `AddIdentity`.

Comment: It sounds like you're using `AddDefaultIdentity`, but you have your own account pages. `AddDefaultIdentity` also adds the default Identity UI. If you don't need or want that, then you need to use `AddIdentity`, instead.

Comment: I am using `AddIdentity`. No call ever to `AddDefaultIdentity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `AddIdentity` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity` if you would like to set by `ConfigureApplicationCookie`.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
            //.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Or you could just try to configure `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to achieve your requirement.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
options =>
{

    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; 
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; 
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);  

});
```

Comment: I am using `AddIdentity` and not `AddDefaultIdentity`.

Comment: @pdube How do you `serivices.AddIdentity` look like?Do not add `AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)`.See my edit anwser.

Comment: You got it. My problem was `.AddDefaultUI(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFramework.Bootstrap4)`
I commented the line and now it redirects to my UI. Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the only thing that solved it was using creating a `PathString` instead of using an string for any path.

```
options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");
```

Comment: tried with `PathString`. Unfortunately, same result.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to explicitly specify the DefaultAuthenticateScheme.

```
.AddAuthentication (options => {
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
  options.LoginPath = "/login";
  // ....
});
```

instead of

```
.AddAuthentication (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```